# discourage images of text on /questions/ask?

Tags: feature-request, question-quality, asking-questions

Is it possible to customise the "Ask a Public Question" page to add some text and a link to discourage posting images of or links to images of text?

I often copy-paste a comment like the following on such questions:

```
[Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.
```

This could probably be worded better, but it would be good if the images-of-text problem was pointed out to people **before** they post.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually [already implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267491/902710) to some degree for *new users*.  It's just that at 15 rep, the warning message goes away so that more experienced users don't see it any longer.  New users that insert text-as-images are usually just ignoring the warning.  And that, in my experience, is *very* common.

As a new user starts to insert an image, they will see this warning in yellow:

> Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

[image]

Perhaps the warning "trigger" could be based on length of time since the user's last question was posted (maybe 6 months?) rather than rep.  That could serve as a "reminder" in case they forgot.

It's not something that we're going to get changed here on meta.unix.stackexchange.com, though.  If you have a suggestion for how the warning might be enhanced or changed, I'd suggest that we need to ask for this to be migrated to the top level Stack Exchange Meta.

Comment: I was hoping it might be possible to add it in, say, the right sidebar, the one labelled "Helpful links" and/or in the https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask page, but I don't know if either of those are customisable by U&L or not.